# Apache Storm: Can I get the data with a TCP Connection?

Tags: java, tcp, bigdata, real-time, apache-storm

I'am developping some application making use of Apache Storm to analyse the data I receive. I want to use it in real-time, and I need to get the data from a server.

My question is related to the connection with the server. Is there any API or something that I can use to make it possible? I have tried to make a simple TCP connection with a java socket in the first Spout, but once I receive the first request, then I can't do the same again.

I have been reading the documentation and also visiting some related questions, but I didn't get the answer.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636231/storm-spout-for-reading-data-from-a-port

Comment: Do you control the server? If so, you might consider using Kafka to transfer the data instead. It gives you a bunch of nice properties (decouple server and spout, ability to replay messages, ability to handle high throughput, ability to partition data), and Storm ships with a spout for reading from Kafka.

If you don't want to use Kafka, you should post the spout code you have so far, so we can help debug it.

Comment: Yes, I'm programming the server side, too. I have tried with @SoheilPourbafrani answer and it seems to work (thank you so much). Now I want to analyze if it works with so many connections.
However, I will try using Kafka, too. It seems interesting. Thank you so much to both of you.